# Setting up ultrawide (3440x1440) 34" monitor

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, display-resolution, external-monitor

I've got a Samsung S34J552 34" especially for using with 3440x1440 resolution but looks like it only work at 2560x1080 with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried o add the 3440x1440 profile using `xrandr` without success (it goes back to the 2560x1080).

Dell XPS 13 9380 - Inter UHD 620 - Monitor connected with HDMI cable, `Linux 5.10.13-051013-generic`

[image]

Comment: In the manual for your monitor they stated that you should be able to use up to 75hz with 3440x1440 using hdmi 2 port. Try it.

Comment: I used a USB-C cable and it was alright! HDMI didn't work, not sure about the display port. I have an RTX A5500 in my laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved by using a DVI - USBC cable and it work great!